# Migrating a Virtual Guest from SAN to Local via the API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to migrate a VSI from SAN to Local disk using the SoftLayer API. I originally tried using the `editObject` method with the `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest` service and although the command returned `true` no transaction was started and the VSI is still using SAN storage. REST or Python examples would be most appreciated.

Using the Chrome Dev tools and migrating the VSI via the Portal shows placeOrder being called (Request URL:https://control.softlayer.com/sales/productorder/placeorder) but it does not appear that placeOrder will accept a VSI ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, you should use [placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method and you need to specify the VSI in "**virtualGuests**" property, below an example

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Method: Post


{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade",
         "packageId":46,
         "prices":[  
            {  
               "id":13899,
               "categories":[  
                  {  
                     "categoryCode":"guest_disk0",
                     "id":81,
                     "name":"First Disk"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "properties":[  
            {  
               "name":"MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
               "value":"2016-11-04T18:51:37.165Z"
            }
         ],
         "virtualGuests":[  
            {  
               "id":25011999
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey**, **25011999** (vsiId) and **13899** (The priceId from the new disk, in this case the local disk price to migrate) with your own information.

---

To get upgrade item prices from your vsi, try the following request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/25011999/getUpgradeItemPrices

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **25011999** with your own information

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder)
- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getUpgradeItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeItemPrices)